# Nested ngx-datatable

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ngx-datatable

Can someone let me know if nested ngx-datatable is possible within another ngx-datatable e.g. I wanted to add a separate ngx-datatable within a column of another datatable.

Here is what i was trying

```js
rows = [
    {
        "name": "Ethel Price",
        "gender": "female",
        "company": "Johnson, Johnson and Partners, LLC CMP DDC",
        "age": 22
    },
    {
        "name": "Claudine Neal",
        "gender": "female",
        "company": "Sealoud",
        "age": 55
    },
    {
        "name": "Beryl Rice",
        "gender": "female",
        "company": "Velity",
        "age": 67
    },
    {
        "name": "Wilder Gonzales",
        "gender": "male",
        "company": "Geekko"
    }] ;
```

```html
<ngx-datatable class="table-bordered schedule-work-grid" [columnMode]="'force'" [rowHeight]="'auto'" [headerHeight]="150"
  *ngIf="locations.length > 0" [rows]="rows">
  <ngx-datatable-column name="Name"></ngx-datatable-column>
  <ngx-datatable-column>
    <template>
      <ngx-datatable class="table-bordered schedule-work-grid" [columnMode]="'force'" [rowHeight]="'auto'" [headerHeight]="150"
        *ngIf="locations.length > 0" [rows]="rows">
        <ngx-datatable-column name="Name"></ngx-datatable-column>
      </ngx-datatable>
    </template>
  </ngx-datatable-column>
  <ngx-datatable-column name="Age"></ngx-datatable-column>
</ngx-datatable>
```

Can someone confirm if nested datatables are possible and if yes, how can i do that?

**Edit**

I want to create below structure

[image: Structure to be created]

As i understand, colspan and rowspan functionality is currently not supported by ngx-datatable. Request you to provide some pointers so that i can go ahead with implementation

Comment: Well i think you should use `row details`. In one column nested datatable table won't fit example: https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-datatable/#

Comment: @TouqeerShafi I need to add set of details in one column. Table structure which i am trying to build is little complex. I am trying to build a POC. Do you suggest use of row_details under each column template?

Comment: Well if you want to show each column details then you should add ICON in that column and when user clicks on that icon it should open a popup. If i had the same scenario i would do that.

Comment: Unfortunately Its not possible since its important to show all detail columns within a single column

Comment: @TouqeerShafi Row Details can't be used as they are displayed as an extension of existing row. I need to show table inline to existing table itself

Comment: Why don't you just use *ngFor and create a fresh custom table within the data table column?

Answer (score 0):

There is an example on the net with nested ngx-datatable, maybe it will be helpful :)
https://codepen.io/SBackUp/pen/MzpzEv

```
 <ngx-datatable
    #prefilteredRestrictionTable
    class='material expandable'
    columnMode="force"
    [headerHeight]="0"
    [footerHeight]="42"
    [rowHeight]="'auto'"
    [scrollbarV]="false"
    [scrollbarH]="false"
    [rows]='displayedData'
    [sortType]="multi"
    [limit]="5">

    <!-- Manage display data columns of first table -->
    <!-- Here I want to group by date from my object and see the date -->
    <ngx-datatable-column 
      *ngFor="let col of columnsNameTableOne"
      [prop]="col.prop"
      [name]="col.name">
      <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
        <div style="font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;" [ngStyle]="{'paddingLeft.px': rowTitleCentered}" (click)="toggleExpandRow(row)">
          {{ row.date }}
        </div>
      </ng-template>
    </ngx-datatable-column>

    <!-- Manage actions columns of first table -->
    <!-- Here I want to manage an action column where I can have an icon to open or close the row specified -->
    <ngx-datatable-column
      [width]="50"
      [resizeable]="false"
      [sortable]="false"
      [draggable]="false"
      [canAutoResize]="false"
      [frozenLeft]="true">
      <ng-template let-row="row" let-expanded="expanded" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
        <a
           href="javascript:void(0)"
          [class.datatable-icon-right]="!expanded"
          [class.datatable-icon-down]="expanded"
          [ngClass]="{'hide': isHidden(row)}"
          title="Expand/Collapse Row"
          class="expand-color"
          (click)="toggleExpandRow(row)">
        </a>
      </ng-template>
    </ngx-datatable-column>

    <!-- Row Detail Template -->
    <!-- Here, based on https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/blob/master/demo/basic/row-detail.component.ts -->
    <!-- I just configured that each row detail is a table -->
    <ngx-datatable-row-detail [rowHeight]="'auto'" class="test">
      <ng-template let-row="row" let-expanded="expanded" ngx-datatable-row-detail-template>
        <div class="offset-subarray">
          <ngx-datatable
            class="material"
            columnMode="force"
            [headerHeight]="60"
            [footerHeight]="42"
            [rowHeight]="'auto'"
            [scrollbarV]="false"
            [scrollbarH]="true"
            [rows]="row.value"
            [sortType]="multi"
            [limit]="10">

            <!-- Manage display data columns -->
            <!-- Here it's to custom each cell of a specific column-->
            <ngx-datatable-column 
              *ngFor="let col of columnsName"
              [prop]="col.prop" 
              [name]="col.name"
              [width]="col.width"
              [ngSwitch]="col.prop">
              <ng-template *ngSwitchCase="'case1'" let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
                <span *ngFor="let x of row.x; let last = last">
                  {{ x }}<span *ngIf="!last">, </span>
                </span>
              </ng-template>
            </ngx-datatable-column>
          </ngx-datatable>
        </div>
      </ng-template>
    </ngx-datatable-row-detail>
    
  </ngx-datatable>
```